# Синхронный вызов

Tags: node.js

В цикле создаю объект, но цикл переходит к следующей итерации не дождавшись выполнения объекта. Как заставить цикл ждать завершения объекта?

Вот пример

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var h = new Horseman(opts);

    h
    .userAgent(userAgent)
    .viewport(1024, 768)
    .click("#btn")
    .waitForNextPage()
    .screenshot('./'+i +'.png'
}
```

[Horseman](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman) не успевает даже загрузить страницу как создается другой объект.

Comment: Даже мой скудный опыт с NodeJS подсказывает, что это не выход. Тут нужно нечто вроде async.series, чтобы следующая итерация была в коллбэке предыдущей.

Comment: А что такое `Horseman`?

Comment: Попробую series.

Comment: [https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman](https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman)

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать? Вам нужно создавать объекты `horseman` и делать скриншоты строго последовательно? Или нужно выполнить какое-то еще действие, когда _все_ скриншоты будут готовы не обращая внимание на количество параллельных запросов и порядок их выполнения?

Comment: Мне надо последовательно. Пока объект не завершит работу цикл должен ждать его завершения.

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с тем, что Хорсмен работает асинхронно, а цикл не ждет,когда закончится выполнение.

Решений два:

1. Можно как-то через промисы попробовать
2. Можно написать с использованием библиотеки co и генераторов control flow

Comment: Попробую промисы.